filezilla server time out connection error
I wanted to share files with friends, so i installed FileZila server on my PC. I made a registration in no-ip.com because of the dynamic IP. Everything is done, but I still cant connect to the server. When I try so, the FTP client says "Error - connection timed out". In the other hand, when I'm trying to connect, in the server side says "login successful". You can see it on the picture. I already made an inbound rule for port 21 in the firewall. I also made a port forwarding in the router. What else can be the problem?
Thanks!
filezilla server

https://superuser.com/q/1309756/213663

Have you opened and forwarded the ports used for passive mode too?

I only forwarded port 21. Are there more ports I need to forward?

Yes, did you read the link I've posted above? Or zillions of other pages on the internet about configuring firewall for FTP?

This question is similar to: Not able to access FTP server from other machines in same LAN when Windows Firewall is ON. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
